# Trouble launching Red Hat(7.7) Subscription-Manager

Tags: rhel, yum, redhat-satellite, abrt

My system config: Red Hat 7.7 [Developer's edition]. Stand Alone system.

```
root@thinkred1cartoon:$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)

root@thinkred1cartoon:$ uname -a
Linux thinkred1cartoon.biz 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Dec 2 08:31:54 EST 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm having problem launching subscription-manager (both CLI or GUI). Error -

```
root@thinkred1cartoon:$ subscription-manager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/subscription-manager", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 3011, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 626, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: six
subscription-manager via CLI or GUI failing to launch
```

I followed this Redhat solution - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3967521

```
1. Uninstall packages installed via pip3

    pip3 pip freeze --local | xargs pip3 uninstall -y

2. Uninstall packages installed via pip

    scl enable python27 bash
    pip freeze --local | xargs pip uninstall -y

3. Uninstalled all python packages from 3rd party listed by command below using "yum remove"

    rpm -qa --queryformat "%{name}-%{version}-%{release}.%{arch}------->%{vendor}\n" | grep -v "Red Hat" | grep -i python

4.  yum reinstall insights-client python-requests python-urllib3

5. yum update -y

6. Rebooted system
```

No luck.

Network is fine. yum works with existing enabled repos and I can go on internet via web browser.

```
root@thinkred1cartoon:$ strace -T -tt -f -v -s 1024 -o register.out insights-client --register
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/insights-client", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 3007, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 728, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 626, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: six
```

System error message -

```
root@thinkred1cartoon:$ tail -f /var/log/messages

Dec 26 15:54:30 thinkred1cartoon python: detected unhandled Python exception in '/usr/sbin/subscription-manager'
Dec 26 15:54:30 thinkred1cartoon python: detected unhandled Python exception in '/usr/sbin/sosreport'
Dec 26 15:54:35 thinkred1cartoon python: communication with ABRT daemon failed: timed out
Dec 26 15:54:35 thinkred1cartoon python: communication with ABRT daemon failed: timed out
Dec 26 15:54:35 thinkred1cartoon abrt-server: sosreport run failed with exit code 1, log follows:
Dec 26 15:54:35 thinkred1cartoon abrt-server: Traceback (most recent call last):
Dec 26 15:54:35 thinkred1cartoon abrt-server:  File "/usr/sbin/sosreport", line 14, in <module>
Dec 26 15:54:35 thinkred1cartoon abrt-server:    from sos.sosreport import main
Dec 26 15:54:35 thinkred1cartoon abrt-server:  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sos/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
Dec 26 15:54:35 thinkred1cartoon abrt-server:    import six
Dec 26 15:54:35 thinkred1cartoon abrt-server: ImportError: No module named six
Dec 26 15:54:35 thinkred1cartoon abrt-server: 'post-create' on '/var/spool/abrt/Python-2019-12-26-15:54:30-20008' exited with 1
Dec 26 15:54:35 thinkred1cartoon abrt-server: Deleting problem directory '/var/spool/abrt/Python-2019-12-26-15:54:30-20008'
Dec 26 15:54:35 thinkred1cartoon python: detected unhandled Python exception in '/usr/sbin/sosreport'
Dec 26 15:54:36 thinkred1cartoon abrt-server: Not saving repeating crash in '/usr/sbin/sosreport'
Dec 26 15:54:36 thinkred1cartoon abrt-server: sosreport run failed with exit code 1, log follows:
Dec 26 15:54:36 thinkred1cartoon abrt-server: Traceback (most recent call last):
Dec 26 15:54:36 thinkred1cartoon abrt-server:  File "/usr/sbin/sosreport", line 14, in <module>
Dec 26 15:54:36 thinkred1cartoon abrt-server:    from sos.sosreport import main
Dec 26 15:54:36 thinkred1cartoon abrt-server:  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sos/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
Dec 26 15:54:36 thinkred1cartoon abrt-server:    import six
Dec 26 15:54:36 thinkred1cartoon abrt-server: ImportError: No module named six
Dec 26 15:54:36 thinkred1cartoon abrt-server: 'post-create' on '/var/spool/abrt/Python-2019-12-26-15:54:30-20024' exited with 1
Dec 26 15:54:36 thinkred1cartoon abrt-server: Deleting problem directory '/var/spool/abrt/Python-2019-12-26-15:54:30-20024'
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Bit of a long shot, but make sure your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` hasn't got any crazy paths inserted into it.

Comment: echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH gives /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64. I made it blank. "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=". Re-ran subscription-manager, same results.

Comment: You’re missing python2’s six module,  not urllib3. You need to reinstall the “python-six” package. Also, anything python 3 related or SCL related is unlikely to be involved.

Comment: Whoa! that was it. Even though `python-six.noarch` is installed, I "`yum reinstall python-six.noarch`" and that worked. Thanks and cheers!